# sketch the graph of the integrand function and use it to help evaluate the integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

sketch the graph of the integrand function and use it to help evaluate the integral.

integration from(1 , -1)  |x|-1

[image]

I think I can evaluate the integration

f(x) = 1/2 x^2 -x+c

but how sketch the graph

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to use the graph alone. [image: Created using Desmos]
Created using [Desmos](http://www.desmos.com)

From the graph, it is clear this is a triangle with base length $2$ and height $-1$. Since we know the integral is the area under the curve, and the area of a triangle is $A=\frac{1}{2}bh$, the integral is:
$$\int_{-1}^1\,(|x|-1)\;\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}(2)(-1)=\boxed{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x\ge 0$, the integrand is $x-1$.  The graph begins at $(0,-1)$ and ends at $(1,0)$.

For $x\le 0$, the integrand is $-x-1$.  The graph begins at $(-1,0)$ and ends at $(0,-1)$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.   I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

The graph can be considered as a piecewise function of two lines either side of $x=0$. Specifically, these are the lines $$y=\pm x-1$$ If you graph these lines it should be clear that the integral can be found piecewise. The integral will be
$$\begin{align}\int\,(|x|-1)\;\mathrm{d}x=\begin{cases}\int\,(x-1)\;\mathrm{d}x\mbox{ for }x\geq 0\\\int\,(-x-1)\;\mathrm{d}x\mbox{ for }x< 0\end{cases}\\=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}x^2-x+c_0\mbox{ for }x\geq 0\\-\frac{1}{2}x^2-x+c_1\mbox{ for }x< 0\end{cases}\\\end{align}$$
Where $c_0,c_1\in\mathbb{R}$

To evaluate the definite integral, then, we have
$$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1\,(|x|-1)\;\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-1}^0\,(|x|-1)\;\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^1\,(|x|-1)\;\mathrm{d}x\\=\left[-\frac{1}{2}x^2-x\right]_{-1}^0+\left[\frac{1}{2}x^2-x\right]_{0}^1\\=\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\\=\boxed{-1}\end{align}$$